# Hibernate hql/criteria result contains collection

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, hibernate-criteria

I have two entities:

```
public class Photo {
   Long id;
   String url;
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name ="user_id")
   User user;
   // other fields and getters/setters
}
```

And second:

```
public class User {
   Long id;
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
   private Collection<Photo> photos;
   // other fields and getters/setters
}
```

I am trying to get this DTO:

```
public class UserDTO {
    Long id;
    List<String> photosUrls;
}
```

But I can't find the right solution. I wrote next criteria - find user with photos by login:

```
getCurrentSession().createCriteria(User.class, "user")
    .createAlias("user.photos", "photos")
    .setProjection(getUserProjection())
    .add(Restrictions.eq("user.login",login))
    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(UserDTO.class))
    .list();
 // projection   
    getUserProjection() {
        return Projections.projectionList()
            .add(Projections.property("user.id"), "id")
            .add(Projections.property("photos"), "url");
    }
```

Also tried with HQL:

```
getCurrentSession()
    .createQuery("select u.id, p.url " +
        " from User u inner join u.photos p " +
        " where u.login LIKE :login")
    .setString("login", login)
    .list();
```

But returned result is `List<Object[]>` type but I need `List<UserDTO>`.

---

Update:

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateSystemException:
>   IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter for property
>   [com.memories.dto.UserDTO.photos(expected type = java.util.List)];
>   target = [com.memories.dto.UserDTO.photos@4e162869], property value =
>   [https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000031744302-0730nk-t500x500.jpg]
>   setter of com.memories.dto.UserDTO.photos; nested exception is
>   IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter for property
>   [com.memories.dto.UserDTO.photos] (expected type = java.util.List)];
>   target = [com.memories.dto.UserDTO.photos@4e162869], property value =
>   [https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000031744302-0730nk-t500x500.jpg]

Comment: @DavidLevesque, yep, of course

Answer (score 1):

I think with the above code all you have to do it is to assign the resultant directly to List and it should work like a breeze. something like this.

```
List<User> userList = yourCriteria.list();
```

Comment: if i try `list.get(0).toString()`  - will throw java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.dto,UserDTO

Comment: That is because your DTO has a list of String. The basic issue lies with your transformation. You should actually transform the result into User rather than UserDTO and write a utility method to convert User to UserDTO.  When hibernate will try to transform the result to UserDTO it will expect UserDTO to have a `String photos` instead of `List<String> photos`. I have edited the answer to reflect the same.

Comment: thank you, i asked because i wanted to know better solution, but, as it turned out, that it is. When i searched variants, i thought that hibernate itself transform data from bd to entity beans. And i thought that i can use hibernate features to do transformation into dto class.

Answer (score 0):

So, i found not the best solution, but...

Firstly, need to get list of entities User:

```
List<User> list = getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery("from USer as u where u.login LIKE :login")
                .setString("login", login)
                .list();
```

Next, we declare in entity User method like this one, which convert `List<Photo>` to `List<String>`:

```
public List<String> getPhotosUrls() {
    List<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>(photos.size());
    for (Photo p : photos)
        urls.add(p.getUrl()));
    return urls;
}
```

And last step is hard-coded creating DTO beans:

```
List<UserDTO> users = new ArrayList<UserDTO>(list.size());
for (User u : list) {
    users.add(new UserDTO(u.id, u.getPhotosUrls));
```

And, of course, you must have `UserDTO(Long id, List<String> urls)` constructor.
If anybody will find better solution, pls write here :)